# How do I have a user pop down to a specific spot on a page when a certain link is clicked

Tags: jquery

Hey guys I am trying to figure out how to have a user, redirect to another page and based on the link clicked; have it put them in that spot of the page that contains the information.

I was planning on coding this in JQuery.  Please let me know :)

Thanks guys and I hope you are having a Tremdous Thursday!!!

EDIT:

```
<div class="online_training">
     <div class="training_image">
       <a href="../services.php">...</a>
     </div><!-- .training_image -->
     <div class="top-textArea">
       <h2><a href="../services.php"></a>....</h2>
       <p>
                       .....
       </p>
     </div><!-- .top-textArea -->
</div><!-- .online_training -->



    I have mutiple of these and so the part to notice where I want to have 
it redirect to and go to that part of the page is the where the .training_image <a> is and the <h2> one is.
```

Comment: Are you in control of the other page?

Comment: Can we see some of your wicked markup?

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this, or any JS at all. Just use a link with `href="secondpageurl#someanchor"` where the second page has an anchor element with the appropriate id.

Comment: Smart man!.....haha my wicked markup....one sec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to just use anchor tags.

On the initial page:

```
<a href="/otherpage#spot1">Go to spot1</a>
```

On otherpage:

```
<a href="#" name="spot1"></a>
```

When otherpage is loaded, it will scroll to the anchor named spot1.

Comment: Wow I totally over thought this!  Thanks :)  Your a blessing my man!

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you can't use the original link href to get there..., you could use a combination of window.location and named anchors.

```
$('a').click(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();

  switch ($(this).prop('data-destination')) {
    case 'api':
      window.location = 'other-page.html#api';
      break;
    case 'tutorial':
      window.location = 'other-page.html#tut';
      break;
    default:
      window.location = 'other-page.html#toc';
      break;
  }
});
```

Where on other-page.html you have those named anchors, e.g.:

```
<a name="toc"></a>
<a name="api"></a>
<a name="tut"></a>
```

The ideal solution would be to structure your links the proper way and avoid using javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a `div` like so at the top or somewhere on the page:

```
<div name="top-div">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="clickMe">Click to Scroll</a>
</div>
```

And then further down the page, you have where you want to go in another `div`:

```
<div id="scrollHere" name="scrollHere">
    Hi
</div>
```

Use something like the following jQuery to get the fancy scroll effect:

```
$("#clickMe").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var scrollTo = $("#scrollHere").css("top");
    var n = $(document).height();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: n }, scrollTo);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azLZp/)

```
$("#clickMe").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.fn.scrollToPos("#scrollHere");
});

$.fn.scrollToPos = function(position) {
    var scrollTo = $(position).css("top");
    var n = $(document).height();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: n }, scrollTo);
    return this;
};
```

[jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/KdUmd/)